# I am trying to make a Chrome extension settings page and its not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Here is the code which I need help on:

```js
if (localStorage.KillTabs == undefined) {
  localStorage.KillTabs = 1;
};
if (document.getElementById('killer')) {
  if document.getElementById('killer').checked = true {
    localStorage.KillTabs = 0;
  }
}
if (localStorage.KillTabs == 1) {
  console.log("Cannot Clear Tabs");
} else {
  console.log("Clearing Tabs...")
  //im going to put something here when i know that this works
}
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="options.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>PrivacyPro Options</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" id="killer">
  <p class="label">Close All Tabs when done</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I think I did it right but I'm not sure. I don't see any errors. I also want the settings to save like when the checkbox is checked I want it to save so every time the extension is ran, the setting activates, and only doesn't activate when the checkbox is unchecked. Any help will be nice, Thank you!

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer and https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: Those examples are confusing to me

Comment: The Google Chrome example literally does exactly what you are trying to do, but correctly uses `chrome.storage`, not `localStorage`: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2

Comment: Is this a class project? Someone else just asked a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751818/how-would-i-save-checkbox-state-in-a-google-chrome-extension-options-page) (but they did not provide any code).

Comment: If the answers from the duplicate(s) don't fully address your question, please edit your question to tell us why.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `storage` interface incorrectly. It's [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) not `localStorage` (even in a browser it would be `localstorage`, all lowercase).

In order to use the `storage` inteface you need to make sure you request storage permissions in the `manifest.json` file.

```
"permissions": [
  "storage"
],
```

Next, you need to use `get()` and `set()` methods on the storage object to get and set values based on a key. This also uses a callback mechanism, so you can't just get the values by calling `get()`.

```
chrome.storage.local.get('killtabs', function(result) {
  if (result === 1) {
    // do something
  }
});
```